# Is there a way to use the <=> operator in a perl if statement?

Tags: perl, if-statement

To start off with, I realize that I *can* write an if statement with this operator that compiles and runs. I'm wondering if there's a way it can be used to make an `if`/`elsif`/`else` block a little more elegant.

I currently have a block of code that looks like this

```
 if( $bill == $ted) {
        # Do some stuff
} elsif( $bill < $ted) {
        # Do different stuff
} else {
        # Do really weird stuff
}
```

So there are specific things I want the script to do based on whether the two values are equal, or if they aren't equal, whichever one is lower. It seems like the `<=>` operator would be well suited to this.

Comment: Personally, I'd be pretty happy with this code as written.  I might reorder the conditions to reflect how likely they are to occur as a possible optimization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the operator returns 1, 0 or -1 depending on the test outcome, which is what `sort` uses.

So it's quite viable to do that. But I'm not sure if it's a particularly clear approach, compared to;

```
if ( $first < $second ) { do X ; next}
if ( $first > $second ) { do Y ; next}
do Z. #$first == $second
```

I'd strongly suggest avoiding single letter variable names, and most especially `$a` and `$b`. It's poor style, and `$a` and `$b` are used by `sort` which could lead to confusion.

Comment: Yeah, I caught the thing about variable names $a and $b a couple minutes after I (carelessly) wrote the question with them. I edited to correct that. FWIW, those aren't the variable names I'm really using.

Answer (score 6):

It's kind of obscure, but you can use the `<=>` operator to get an element of a dispatch table:

```
(   sub { say 'they are the same' },
    sub { say 'x is greater' },
    sub { say 'x is lesser' }
)[$x <=> $y]->();
```

It's based on the fact that the index -1 returns the last element of a list.

Using a hash might be more readable.

```
{    0 => sub { say 'they are the same' },
     1 => sub { say 'x is greater' },
    -1 => sub { say 'x is lesser' }
}->{ $x <=> $y }->();
```

Comment: Technically correct, but I think I'd be giving people who did that in production code a pretty hard time over it.

Comment: Clever.  Perhaps too clever?

Comment: I like this one a lot. Especially since I'm iterating this comparison over thousands of data points, so to me it's nice that each comparison only needs to made one time (as opposed to twice if they're not equal). But this looks like the kind of thing I'd look at a year from now and not know what in the world it means.

Comment: @GernBlanston This “optimization” is very likely not worth it even from a performance standpoint: subroutine calls tend to be measurably more expensive than simple operations like (non-overloaded) comparisons or if-statements. I'd bet the code in your question is already the fastest, followed by tjd's for-if pseudoswitch.

Comment: OTOH, if the initial expression is `[complicated_function_x() <=> complicated_function_y()]`, then using `<=>` might save you a couple of function calls.

Comment: @mob `my $temp_x = complicated_function_x(); my $temp_y = complicated_function_y();` would accomplish much the same goal.

Answer (score 2):

This uses the result of `<=>` as an array index like ***choroba's*** answer, but there is no need to store and call anonymous subroutines

I still wouldn't use it in live code

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

for my $x ( 1 .. 3 ) {
    say ['equal', 'greater than', 'less than']->[$x <=> 2];
}
```

#### output

```
less than
equal
greater than
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't call it elegant, but you could use a given/when to catch all the outcomes:

```
    use strict;
    use 5.10.0;
    use feature "switch";
    use experimental "smartmatch";

    my $x = 1;
    given( $x <=> 2 ){
        when(-1){
            say "stuff"
        }
        when(0){
            say "diff stuff"
        }
        when(1){
            say "other stuff"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking a cue from draxil w/o the experimental features:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $x = 1;
for ( $x <=> 2 ){
    if ($_ == -1){
        say "stuff"
    }
    if ($_ == 0){
        say "diff stuff"
    }
    if ($_ == 1){
        say "other stuff"
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks essentially equivalent to how it's already written, just with the additional evaluation in the for() statement. I'm not looking to use the <=> operator just for the sake of using it. Just wondering if there was some common function that already did what I'm doing with the if/elsif/else block.

Answer (score 0):

```perl
{
    goto (qw( EQ GT LS ))[$x <=> $y];
    LS:
        say('less');
        last;
    EQ:
        say('equal');
        last;
    GT:
        say('greater');
}
```

[But](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/goto.html):

> This isn't necessarily recommended if you're optimizing for maintainability.